# Add block in header layout

Tags: layout, header, custom-block

I have added my custom module block in header in layout like below

**pinsearch.xml**

```
 <default> 
   <reference name="header">
        <block type="core/template" name="pinsearch" as="pinSearch" template="pinsearch/pinsearch.phtml" output="toHtml"/>
     </reference> 
  <default>
```

**pinsearch.phtml**

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl()."pinsearch/index/search"?>" method="get" id="search_pin_form">
<div class="input-box">
    <label for="search"><?php echo $this->__('Search:') ?></label>
     <input id="pinsearch" type="search" name="<?php echo "pin" ?>" value="" class="input-text required-entry" maxlength="" placeholder="<?php echo $this->__('Enter here...') ?>" />
    <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Search') ?>" class="button search-button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Search') ?></span></span></button>
</div>
```

In frontend, I got my custom search form but not in header. This form showing after **wrapper div block**

[image]

When i add this block in footer only, its showing on both **footer and after wrapper div block** too.

I'm totally confusing. Have any idea why its proceeding like this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you add a block directly inside `header` block, magento will put your block just after all of it's child block that are added via other layout xml files that are processed before your `pinsearch.xml`.

Basically a header block contains following blocks by default. This is added via `page.xml` which will get processed before your `pinsearch.xml`

```
<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
    <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
    <block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
        <label>Navigation Bar</label>
        <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
    </block>
    <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="top.container" as="topContainer" translate="label">
        <label>Page Header</label>
        <action method="setElementClass"><value>top-container</value></action>
    </block>
    <block type="page/html_welcome" name="welcome" as="welcome"/>
</block>
```

see `top.container` (which is the wrapper block that you are mentioning, I hope) block is loading here. So when we add your block directly under `header` block, it just come just below `welcome` (This is not accurate. But if we consider `page.xml` only, this is true :-))

So if you need your block just inside the wrapper block, then what you need to is include your block inside wrapper block itself

```
<default> 
   <reference name="header">
       <reference name="top.container">
            <block type="core/template" name="pinsearch" template="pinsearch/pinsearch.phtml"/>
       </reference>
     </reference> 
  <default>
```

Now suppose you need to include the block as child of `header` block itself, but need to display above the wrapper block (or any other child block), then what you need to do is.

```
<default> 
   <reference name="header">
        <block type="core/template" name="pinsearch" as="pinSearch" template="pinsearch/pinsearch.phtml"/>
     </reference> 
  <default>
```

Then go to `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/page/html/header.phtml` and then specify your block wherever you needed to display it as like this

```
  <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('pinSearch') ?>
```

Hope that clears your doubt.. Happy coding sis :-)

Comment: Now showing twice. Below navigation menu and after wrapper block

Comment: you need to remove the `output="toHtml"`. I have edited answer accordingly